# Imageresizer Preset Plugin

Tags: imageresizer

We are testing the Imageresizer.net and have found that the Preset Plugin seems to only work with width and height parameters and completely ignores the mode parameter i.e. mode=crop.
Is this a bug or simply not supported.

Many thanks

Comment: Share what you've tried; configuration and code is required on SO.

Comment: Here is the web.config settings                                 <presets onlyAllowPresets="false">
<preset name="galthumb" settings="width=105;height=57; mode=crop">
 </presets>

Comment: Is that a space before 'mode'? That would cause it - querystrings are space-sensitive.

Comment: YES! That was the problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supported, but know that the presets `settings` and `defaults` values must be valid command/querystrings. Spaces or typos in the command string will cause that command (and potentially the rest) not to function.